# Handling a post in angular unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

In my Angular app, when my view loads, a POST is made. At first I was getting this error:

```
"Unexpected request: POST /api/stuff
```

Now, however, I have inserted this code:

```
$httpBackend.expectPOST("/api/stuff",[{}]).respond(200,{});
```

This removes the initial error but instead I am left with this error:

```
"message": "Expected POST /api/stuff with different data
EXPECTED: [{}]
GOT:      {}"
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to resolve this, that would be greatly appreciated. If more code is needed please ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are calling $http.post with "{}" instead of the expected "[{}]". What this means and how to solve it depends on the context, please add the whole unit-test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the input data and output data.

For example

```
var inputData = {  
   name : 'xyz',
   email : 'rrr@ggg.com'
}

var outputData = {
   id : 'L56757',
   company : 'dsgdsg'
}

$httpBackend.expectPOST("/api/stuff", inputData).respond(200, outputData );
$httpBackend.flush();
```